# WebSphere & javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider not a subtype

Tags: java, websphere, cxf, jax-ws, classloader

I have an app deployed on IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.0.
When the app tries to call a remote web service, I get

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider not a subtype.
```

It seems that WAS is picking (probably bundled) Axis2 impl. of the JAX-WS Provider class instead of the CXF one that I want to use.

- The app WAR does not come with Axis2 impl. of javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
- The app WAR contains a CXF jar with the Provider impl., org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl

I tried

- Classloaders set to "Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)"
- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html
- Set the com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine property to true (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html)
- adding "-Djavax.xml.ws.spi.Provider=org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl" in JVM arguments for the server

Neither of them helped, I still have the same exception.

Interestingly when I print `System.getProperty(“javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider”)` from a test JSP within the app, it outputs `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl`.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a WebSphere Fix Pack 9 solved the issue completely.